# How to select Multiple Images from Photo Library?

Tags: ios

```
- (void)pickImage {

  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  picker.delegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  _image = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  [_imageView setImage:_image];
  [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: “CTAssetsPickerController is an iOS controller that allows picking multiple photos and videos from user’s photo library. The usage and look-and-feel are just similar to UIImagePickerController.”

REF:http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/select-multiple-photos-videos-photo-library.html

Comment: how to edit these above code or any other options

Answer (score 1):

You can't select multiple photos or videos simultaneously
You have to use custom ImagePicker. And I think [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) is the best option in my opinion.

There is also some other library that can be used..
[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)
[WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController)
[QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController)
[ZCImagePickerController](https://github.com/iamzcc/ZCImagePickerController)
[CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController)
[AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController)

Comment: I saw the demo but i have no idea to how to import into my app will you please help me how to import this into my app and how to use it

Comment: http://tricksni.blogspot.com/2013/03/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using.html
here is the tutorial for one. read carefully, where you are showing UIImagePicker, you have to call the the image picker and pass it into an array  and do your stuff as you want

Comment: and sorry for being so late . I was out there